# Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException

Tags: unity-container

After installing my WPF application and I try to run the application it crashes and records the error below in the Event Viewer. Anyone has ideas?

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application: MyApp.Windows.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride>)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at MyApp.Windows.IoC.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]()
   at MyApp.Windows.Navigation.NavigationController.Navigate(System.String, System.Windows.Controls.UserControl)
   at MyApp.Windows.LoginWindow..ctor()
   at MyApp.Windows.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at MyApp.Windows.App.Main()
```

Comment: Can you get the actual exception message, not just the stack trace? That'll tell you exactly what the container was doing when it failed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Chris. Managed to trap the actual exception which provided much more specific information. It ended up being the connection to SQL Server which couldn't be established.

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is pretty old now, but I just wanted to say I just had the same exact exception, and the solution was also pretty much the same.

The event viewer had the same output as in Joe's case.
I managed to catch the exception in VS and it showed me a "ResolutionFailedException while setting value for property Views.MainWindow".

The real problem however was that entity framework tried to build the SqlCE database in a directory that did not exist.. Pretty basic, but the exception was so weird I though i would share my findings.